# Error in mounted hook (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, runtime-error

I have created a project with Vue. I'm trying to show some data through a chart using the ChartJs library, to capture the information I use axios. I've been getting this error since the beginning but I don't know what I'm missing, any idea?

```js
async created() {
  const { data } = await axios.get("https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/confirmed");
  
  var c=0
  for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){
    if(data[i].countryRegion=="India"){
        if (data[i].provinceState in this.labels){
          continue
        }
        else{
          this.labels.push(data[i].provinceState)
          this.confirmed.push(data[i].confirmed)
          c=c+1
          if(c==28){
            break
          }
        }
    }
  }
  console.log(this.labels)
}
```

In the error message it also mentions this function which is in the LineChart.vue file

```html
<template>
  <canvas ref="chartLine" width="900px" height="250px"></canvas>
</template>

<script>
import Chart from 'chart.js';
export default {
  props: {
    label: {
      type: Array
      
    },
    chartData: {
      type: Array
    },
  },
  async mounted() {
    await new Chart(this.$refs.myChart, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: this.label,
        datasets: [
        {
            label: 'CASES',
            borderColor: 'rgba(245, 229, 27, 1)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 236, 139,0.2)',
            data: this.chartData,
        }
        ]
      },
      options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
    }
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Look for places where you invoke the .length property

Comment: I've been checking, but I don't use that property anywhere, that's why I'm so confused, I looked at questions where they have the same problem, but they do use the length property

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: I already put the code in the question, I'm sorry I just started here today so I'm still a little slow.

Comment: can you check on the value of `this.$refs.myChart` inside `mounted` hook that might be undefined

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. The error means that something that is supposed to be an array is undefined in `mounted`. `chartData` or `label`. Currently only you debug them. It's unknown how snippet 1 and 2 are related. If data for those props is set asynchronously, you obviously can't render a chart until it's set. `new Chart` doesn't return a promise and it doesn't make sense to await it, this just makes call stack more complicated to debug.